# Control another user's session in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysqli, session-variables, logout

Is it possible in PHP to select a particular user from a database and edit their session other than the current user? Say in the case of when an account type changes or account is deleted or disabled, force `session_destroy` of that user. If so how?

Comment: When you check if that user is logged in, you can also check, if the account still exists in db and is "active". Or you need to store his session id in your users table, then you can destroy his session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions are a simple way to store data for individual users against a unique session ID. This can be used to persist state information between page requests for your problem i don't think sessions will be optimal solution however you can do this, Store a Boolean in your database (say Aaccount_status) that would be checked every time the user logs in if the the Boolean ( Aaccount_status) is `true` then the user will have no problem  logging himself in otherwise when the user deactivates or deletes the account set the Boolean equal to `false`.For more information about sessions check this out http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php